# How to test Context file using Jest or testing Library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, babel-jest

I am new to testing, can anyone guide me on how to test context.
I have called an API inside a function how do I test response or a function using jest or a react testing library.

CodesandBox Link: [Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-mcclintock-tn7w4?file=/src/Dashboard.js)

**context API file**

where I have called the API in userDataFunc, I would like to test the function exist or not and its response both bor success response and catch response

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const globalC = createContext();

export class Gprov extends Component {
  state = {
    authLogin: null,
    authLoginerror: null,
    count: 1,
    user: null
  };
  componentDidMount() {}

  userDataFunc = async () => {
    await axios(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          this.setState({
            userData: res.data
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) =>
        this.setState({
          userDataerror: err
        })
      );
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      user: this.state.username
    });
  };
  render() {
    
    return (
      <globalC.Provider
        value={{
          ...this.state,
          loginData: this.loginData,
          handleChange: this.handleChange,
          handleSubmit: this.handleSubmit,
          userDataFunc: this.userDataFunc
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </globalC.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: I have shared a codesandbox link. There i have only tested dashboard page which is working fine.. but i don't know how to proceed with context page to tect function and response   @juliomalves

Comment: import React from "react";
 import { Gprov } from "./context";
 import { create } from "react-test-renderer";
 import { waitForElement, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react";
 import axiosMock from "axios";
 
 afterEach(cleanup)
 
 describe("Context Page", async () => {
   const component = create(<Gprov />);
   const instance = component.getInstance();
 
   it("it updates dose correctly", () => {
     console.log("instance", instance);
     expect(instance.state.userData).toStrictEqual([]);
   });
   it("fetches data and display", async () => {});
 });

Comment: Looks like there's a more detailed version of this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66455985/how-to-test-function-which-call-api. I'd consider closing this one.

Comment: Yes.  I have updated can you help me out on that..